# Making a tikzpicture Subfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats

I'm trying to create a subfigure with my bar chart. However, the `\pgfplotstableread` command seems to be getting in the way of the subfigure function. Any help is very much appreciated... Thank you in advance!

```
\begin{figure}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Test, 0
Rater1- Rater 2+ (Disagreement), 0.007
Rater1+ Rater 2- (Disagreement), 0.58
Rater1- Rater 2- (Agreement), 98.47
Rater1+ Rater 2+ (Agreement), 0.95
}
\piedata
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.42\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
xlabel={\% Observed},
yticklabels from table={\piedata}{[index]0},
ytick=data,
axis lines=left,
xmin=0,
enlarge y limits,
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}
]
\addplot table[x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\piedata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.42\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
%%insert other subfigure here}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please make your code snippet compilable ...

Comment: Have you tried putting `\pgfplotstableread` inside the subfigure environment?

Comment: After successfully guessing the packages you used and correcting the mistake of not closing both `\resizebox`es, it worked just fine. There is a `}` missing after `\end{tikzpicture}` and the second `\resizebox` is also not complete.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved by correcting some typos.

Comment: @StefanPinnow It's a bit more constructive if we ask the commenter first to write an answer first. They might have gotten caught up with other things.

Comment: @Mike Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @samcarter: ok, done

Answer (score 4):

After successfully guessing the packages you used and correcting the mistake of not closing both `\resizebox`es, it worked just fine.

There was a `}` missing after `\end{tikzpicture}` and the second `\resizebox` was also not complete (see comments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Test, 0
Rater1- Rater 2+ (Disagreement), 0.007
Rater1+ Rater 2- (Disagreement), 0.58
Rater1- Rater 2- (Agreement), 98.47
Rater1+ Rater 2+ (Agreement), 0.95
}
\piedata
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.42\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar,
xlabel={\% Observed},
yticklabels from table={\piedata}{[index]0},
ytick=data,
axis lines=left,
xmin=0,
enlarge y limits,
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}
]
\addplot table[x index=1,y expr=\coordindex] {\piedata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}} % added } here to close the first \resizebox 
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.42\textwidth}
        \centering
        % and closed this one too
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{insert other subfigure here}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Btw.: the usual error message for these things is

```
File ended while scanning use of ...
```

followed by some command name, which may be unknown to most users. But it tells you, that something wasn't closed. To get a hint where to find the problem, you should look into the log file itself. TeXStudio and other TeX IDEs tend to only tell half the story in the error tab. In the log file (shown in the log tab, go there by selecting the error in the error tab, then change to the log tab) the error looks like this:

```
Runaway argument?
{ \begin {tikzpicture} \begin {axis}[ xbar, xlabel={\% Observed}, yti\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \Gscale@box@dd.
...
```

The interesting part is the line before `File ended ...`. It is the start of the argument which wasn't closed with `}`. There are no line breaks here, but usually it's enough to find it in the source.